# Custom field type column editor in Sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, column, custom-field-types, settings, editor

I would need some help that i was not able to google it and if there is somebody who could help me that would be great.

I successfully created a custom field type

Now what im looking for is some walkthrogh how to create a sharepoint designer column editor for this field.

for example:
i open a list that contians my custom field type in sharepoint designer
then click edit columns

[image]

now i see all columns in my list ("picker" is my custom field type)
when i right click the "Title" i choose "Column Settings" the Column Editor will open

[image]
[image: Column Editor]

but when i try to open "Column Settings" for picker (my custom field type) i just got error message:
"Column Settings are not supported for this column type"

so my question: is thare any way to define this column editor for my custom field type?
if there is no possibility to create such editor i will need som proof for my boss...because somebody from some forum told me it is not possible ... this won't be accepted :D

Thank you for advise

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your method is not working.  If you're really new to Sharepoint maybe it's worth me mentioning a different approach -> have you tried creating columns through either the Site Settings or List Settings?

If you create at the List level > List Settings > scroll down the settings page until you reach 'Create Column' > select this and you're taken to a page to define your column type.

If you create at the Site Settings level, the steps are the same, except you'll need to go to your List settings and add your new column to your list by using the 'Add from existing site columns'.

Comment: My column picker is a custom field type derived from lookup field....created by following these steps...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861799(v=office.12).aspx ...i can understand why it is not supported...because its custom field type and any editor hasnt been defined